# cannot launch matlab remotely on mac from linux in the terminal

Tags: linux, macos, matlab, remote-access

After I ssh to the mac desktop from linux Suse, I could not open matlab even without GUI. The mac desktop has mac OS 10.6. At the beginning, I thought the reason is that I did not use -X flag. However, after I tried "ssh -X remote", it still could not work. Also, Whatever I tried any option to open matlab like "matlab -nonjvm", "matlab -nodesktop" and so on, it always reported the same error message:

Mon Sep  3 16:00:41  java[74327] : kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Could not open display. Exiting.

I really appreciated if anyone can answer my question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you seem to have a problem with the Display variable.
Try 'matlab -nodisplay' - this should turn off the display features. The '-nojvm' switch does not - you can still show figures on the display.

Also, try to inspect what the DISPLAY variable says after you ssh to your Mac (echo $DISPLAY).